# Resetting the timestamp of a cached data entry to now()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to reset the timestamp on a cached Entry. I want to know how to achieve that.

Right now i am creating a new instance of  `MemoryCacheEntryOptions`

```
        private MemoryCacheEntryOptions GetCacheOptions()
        {
            return new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)); // Cache for some seconds.
        }
```

I want to be able to reset the `SetSlideExpiration()` to start counting from Zero (0)second, every time a cached data is present in the `MemoryCacheEntry`.

So if

```
public bool hasCached(string key, byte[] values)
{
  return _memoryCache.TryGetValue(GetDocStoreKey(key), out values);
}
```

returns `true` i should be able to reset the SetSlideExpiration to start counting from beginning.

Comment: You don't need to do that explicitly, that's what a sliding expiration means: each time you access the cached item it will reset the sliding expiration clock.

Comment: Thanks @IanMercer, but `SetSlideExpiration()` is explained in the api docs as : _Sets how long the cache entry can be inactive (e.g. not accessed) before it will be removed. This will not extend the entry lifetime beyond the absolute expiration (if set)._

Comment: @davidzagi and you _do_ want to extend the entry lifetime beyond the absolute expiration? Bump the absolute expiration time when the entry is accessed? Maybe you can explain what you want to do with a (currently failing) test in your question.

Comment: Assuming you used the cache options in your `Set` call, then `TryGetValue` will reset the sliding window each time you call it; you don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))` will automatically reset the cache timestamp every time the item in the cache is accessed

```
 public object GetFile(string key)
 {
   return (_memoryCache.Get(Cache(key));
 }
```

So if the cache entry was access like this `resultFromCache = _cacheServiceClass.GetFile(cacheKey);` the MemoryCacheEntryOptions() will reset
`SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))` every time.